# Installation Openshift Origin with oo-install-20140725-1501

Tags: installation, openshift-origin

I am having a problem with installation of Openshift origin. I tried the installation
Openshift origin 3.0 on CentOS6.5 by using below command and I got succeeded at 2 weeks ago.

## sh <(curl -s https://install.openshift.com/) -w origin_deploy

But now, it says an error message that I don't know how to fix it.

```
Validating deployment configuration... /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:328:in `are_accounts_valid?': undefined local variable or method `host' for #<Installer::Deployment:0x7f2ee4552048> (NameError)
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:319:in `each'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:319:in `are_accounts_valid?'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:316:in `each'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:316:in `are_accounts_valid?'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/deployment.rb:307:in `is_valid?'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/lib/installer/assistant.rb:58:in `run'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/bin/oo-install:187
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/bin/oo-install:185:in `loop'
        from /tmp/oo-install-20140725-1501/bin/oo-install:185
```

Please give me some advise to solve this issue. I guess that they have released new version during 2 weeks.